# Matplotlib does not show dates on the chart

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

[image]I started to learn Matplotlib, I did the pip install and everything runs fine, I was able to create the chart with the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_can = pd.read_excel(    
    'Canada.xlsx',
    sheet_name='Canada by Citizenship',
    skiprows=range(20),
    skip_footer=2)

def data_format(df_can):
    df_can.index.values
    df_can.index.tolist()
    df_can.drop(['AREA','REG','DEV','Type','Coverage'], axis=1, inplace=True)
    df_can.rename(columns={'OdName':'Country', 'AreaName':'Continent', 'RegName':'Region'}, inplace=True)
    df_can['Total'] = df_can.sum(axis=1)
    df_can.set_index('Country', inplace=True)

data_format(df_can)

df_can.columns = list(map(str, df_can.columns))
years = list(map(str, range(1980, 2014)))


df_can.sort_values(by='Total', ascending=False, axis=0, inplace=True)


df_top5 = df_can.head(5)

df_top5 = df_top5[years].transpose()

df_top5.plot(kind='area', figsize=(14, 8)) 

plt.title('Immigration Trend of Top 5 Countries')
plt.ylabel('Number of Immigrants')
plt.xlabel('Years')

plt.show()
```

However, when the plot shows, I can't see the dates, which I think they should show up, I was trying to search but the code is good, So it might be something in regards to the visualization tool.

Any thoughts? thanks in advance.

Comment: is `Canada.xlsx` public available somewhere?

Comment: @DynoFu yes it does, I downloaded the data to my pc.

Comment: @MrT you can get the date from the following link: http://www.un.org/en/development/desa/population/migration/data/empirical2/migrationflows.shtml , I have added an image to show what I mean with I can't see the dates. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you convert your data into strings with

```
df_can.columns = list(map(str, df_can.columns))
years = list(map(str, range(1980, 2014)))
```

making your plot a categorical plot. There are ways to label your plot afterwards, but why not simply keeping your numerical data?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_can = pd.read_excel(    
    'Canada.xlsx',
    sheet_name='Canada by Citizenship',
    skiprows=range(20),
    skip_footer=2)

def data_format(df_can):
    df_can.index.values
    df_can.index.tolist()
    df_can.drop(['AREA','REG','DEV','Type','Coverage'], axis=1, inplace=True)
    df_can.rename(columns={'OdName':'Country', 'AreaName':'Continent', 'RegName':'Region'}, inplace=True)
    df_can['Total'] = df_can.sum(axis=1)
    df_can.set_index('Country', inplace=True)

data_format(df_can)

df_can.sort_values(by='Total', ascending=False, axis=0, inplace=True)
#keep only columns with yearly data
df_top5 = df_can.head(5).drop(["Continent", "Region", "DevName", "Total"], axis = 1).transpose()

df_top5.plot(kind='area', figsize=(14, 8)) 

plt.title('Immigration Trend of Top 5 Countries')
plt.ylabel('Number of Immigrants')
plt.xlabel('Years')

plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the advise you are right. It did work, Will take the conversion of the data to str next time.